# If $x^2 - 3x + 1 = 0$, what is the value of $x^2 + (1/x)^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x^2 - 3x + 1 = 0$, what is the value of $x^2 + \left(1/x\right)^2$ ?

A. $7$

B. $\frac{7 − 3\sqrt 5}2$

C. $9$

D. $\frac{7 + 3\sqrt 5}2$

E. $10$

I don't really know how to solve this. I tried to replace  $x^2$  with $3x-1$ but I didn't get anything.

Comment: Hint: divide your initial quadratic by $x$ ...

Answer (score 7):

Letting $t=x+\frac 1x$, we have 
$$xt=x^2+1=3x\Rightarrow t=3$$
because $x\not= 0$.

Hence, we have $$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}=\left(x+\frac 1x\right)^2-2=t^2-2=3^2-2=7.$$

Answer (score 2):

or you can solve your quadratic equation and you will get
$$x_1=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
$$x_2=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
plugging this in $x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$ you will get $7$.
Sonnhard.

Answer (score 2):

Observation (1):

For $x\ne 0$
$$x^2 - 3x +1 = 0$$
$$\downarrow$$
$$x - 3 + 1/x = 0$$
$$\downarrow$$
$$x + 1/x = 3$$
(Mentioned by Mark Bennet in the comments also)

Observation (2)

$$\left(x + \frac 1x\right)^2 = x^2 + 2 + \frac 1{x^2} = \left( x^2 + (1/x)^2 \right) + 2$$