# If $x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}=66$ then what is the value of $\frac{x^2-1+2x}{x}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\displaystyle x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}=66$ then what is the value of $\displaystyle\frac{x^2-1+2x}{x}$?

My work: $\displaystyle \bigg(x+\frac{1}{x}\bigg)^2-2=66$

$\displaystyle \bigg(x+\frac{1}{x}\bigg)^2=64$

$\displaystyle x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+2=64$

Comment: Dupe of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/940461/97045

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain:

$$\displaystyle x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}=66$$

$$\therefore \left( x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+2=66$$ OR $$\left( x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2=64$$ which implies $$x-\frac{1}{x}=\pm 8$$

Now, your question wants you to find out $x-\frac{1}{x}+2$ which implies that the answer is probably $$+8+2=10$$ OR $$-8+2=-6$$

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{x^2-1+2x}{x} = x - \dfrac{1}{x} + 2$, but $66 = x^2 + \dfrac{1}{x^2} = \left(x - \dfrac{1}{x}\right)^2 + 2$. Can you take it from here.

Comment: +1 for the initial heads up. I just detailed your method to explain it step by step in my answer.

Comment: $(x-1/x)^2=64$   $X^2+1/x^2-2=64$